# pull occurrences for species with multiple taxon IDs in R OBIS

Tags: r

I'm using R OBIS (robis package) to pull occurrences of a bunch of species. Importantly, I only have the scientific name of species.

The problem is, some species have multiple taxon IDs in OBIS. For example, Ceramium virgatum, a red algae, has 2 IDs in OBIS:

- Ceramium virgatum, JD Hooker & Harvey, 1848, taxon ID: 377258
- Ceramium virgatum, Roth 1797, taxon ID: 178915

When I use the `occurrence(scientificname = "Ceramium virgatum")` command using the species name as the identifier, I get only occurrences of the first ID (377258), which, in this case, only has 4 occurrence records.

I can manually pull `occurrence(taxonid = 178915)` to get occurrences of the other ID, which returns a dataset with the same value in the scientificName column, but I wouldn't have known this existed if I didn't manually look at the OBIS map explorer (https://mapper.obis.org/?taxonid=377258,178915).

How can I programatically make sure that I get all occurrences in the case that OBIS has multiple entries for more species in my list?

```
library(robis)
library(dplyr)


# the Problem: Ceramium virgatum has 2 taxonIDs in obis - 377258 and 178915,
# but when calling only by Sci Name, robis only returns records from one of these IDs

# using occurrence() by sci name alone, it  pulls 4 records from the first ID, and omits second ID
occurrence(scientificname = "Ceramium virgatum") %>% 
  summarize(n_records = n(), 
            id = unique(aphiaID),
            scientificName = unique(scientificName)) 
#   n_records     id
#     <int>      <int>
#       4        377258
  

# using occurrence() by ID #2, it only pulls 15872 records from the second ID
occurrence(taxonid = 178915) %>%
  summarize(n_records = n(), 
            id = unique(aphiaID),
            scientificName = unique(scientificName)) 
#   n_records     id        scientificName   
#    <int>       <int>           <chr>            
#    15872       178915     Ceramium virgatum


# I can pull all records by calling both ID names (and they return same sci name),
# but for the rest of my species, I only have scientific names, not individual OBIS IDs. 
occurrence(taxonid = c(377258,178915)) %>%
  group_by(aphiaID) %>%
  summarize(n_records = n(), 
            id = unique(aphiaID),
            scientificName = unique(scientificName)) 
#   aphiaID     n_records     id         scientificName   
#   <int>         <int>      <int>          <chr>            
#     178915     15872       178915     Ceramium virgatum
#     377258         4       377258     Ceramium virgatum
```

Comment: we have a python package for OBIS API as well - *pyobis*. I hope you'd have a look at it, [it's pretty much powerful and well-documented!](https://pypi.org/project/pyobis/)